# Do Euler's idoneal numbers allow to get prime power numbers?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

I found out this information on wikipedia:
"In mathematics, Euler's idoneal numbers (also called suitable numbers or convenient numbers) are the positive integers D such that any integer expressible in only one way as $x^2 ± Dy^2$ (where $x^2$ is relatively prime to $Dy^2$) is a **prime power** or **twice a prime power**. In particular, a number that has two distinct representations as a sum of two squares is composite. Every idoneal number generates a set containing infinitely many primes and missing infinitely many other primes. "

Do we have this relationship $2n+1=x^2 ± Dy^2=p^k$ if the integer $2n+1$ is expressible in only one way with $D$ an idoneal number ?
Is that really a prime power $p^k$ with $k>=1$ ? Or do we only have $k=1$ ?
Which values can take the variable $k$ ? is it an odd or an even number or both ? Are there an infinity ?

Does it exist a book or an article about this topic with a proof of this result ?

Thanks for your help